# Do I have options on creating multiple license types for a single app published on AppExchange?

Tags: appexchange, isv, licenses, packagelicense

As far as I know this use case isn't clear in the documentation, so I'm going to elaborate a bit here:

The use case is an app that can be divided onto two parts, pre-sales (1) and after-sales (2) (but not quite service, more on the reporting part). There is a certain feature involving Apex, triggers and a component for #1 and another feature involving Apex and a component for #2.

Those two features work independently from each other, so in theory those could be two different license types, as the theoretical users for those two are different users.

I'm wondering if it is possible to sell two different licenses for the same app, one for each feature. So in a hypothetical scenario the subscriber could purchase 10 licenses for #1 and 5 licenses for #2, at different prices each, for example.

Is this doable with a single app? Or do I need to split the app into a core app plus two other extensions that implement the specific licenses? Would those two be different listings on AppExchange or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new [Licensing Components (Developer Preview)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/partner_licensing_platform_components.htm) allows you have a single app with Licensed Permission Sets that can be individually sold and billed as addons. This would have a single AppExchange listing, and you could define a pricing model for each license type. However, this is a pilot program, so you'll have to contact your AE for details on availability. If you can get in on this, it would be your best option.

You can also use 2GP (Second Generation Packaging) to share a namespace with two or more packages. In the most trivial model, you could create two packages, and list each on the AppExchange. Since they're in the same namespace, they can even communicate with each other if both are installed. They can be individually licensed and billed as such. This would be the preferred model if you can't have access to the pilot, for now. Licenses are assigned to users to allow access to a specific feature.

You could also use a variant where you have three packages, one that acts as a shared code/metadata repository, and one each for the two apps. This might still be two listings, but subscribers would have to manually install the base package before installing either of the other two. I'm not sure how this would affect Security Reviews, though, there may be extra fees associated with a three-package model as opposed to just two standalone apps. Again, for non-Site licenses, each package would have to be assigned to users. The base package itself would just be a Site-wide license, since its the other two packages that provide licensed access to the features.

Finally, you could use a 1GP (First Generation Packaging) or 2GP package, and have extensions that you install. This can be detected at runtime to wall off parts of an app if they don't have an appropriate package installed. However, you end up having to build a custom licensing system, and it won't be supported by Checkout directly. You're allowed to bill in pretty much any manner you wish, but it's a very manual process to have just a single listing *and* not use Licensed Permission Sets. Consider this a last resort.

---

Summary:

> Is this doable with a single app?

If you can use Licensed Permission Sets (LPS), it's trivial. If not, it's doable with the FeatureManagement class, but requires a lot of supporting code. I'd avoid this because of the complexity it introduces.

> Or do I need to split the app into a core app plus two other extensions that implement the specific licenses?

You can do three packages, but two is better; this lets you just have the core metadata you need in each package, and licensing is simplified. The three package model would only help if you need to share metadata across these two packages.

> Would those two be different listings on AppExchange or what?

Not every package ends up on the AppExchange; that's up to your design choices:

| Listings | Design |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Single Package with LPS |
| 1 | Core package with unlisted extensions |
| 2 | 2GP standalone packages |
| 2 | 2GP packages with dependency on third unlisted core |

It is not required to have a listing to manage licenses in the LMA (Licensing Management App), only that these packages are linked to the LMA/LMO (Licensing Management Org).

Comment: That explains a lot, thank you so much! You mentioned that a listing is not necessary to manage licenses in the LMA, so that means we don't exactly need to go through the whole security review, fees, waiting if we want to distribute/license the app on our own (that is: without _publishing on the AppExchange_)?

Comment: @RenatoOliveira You need the LMA to do licensing, which means you have to be in the Partner Program to gain access to the LMA to link your packages to begin with. Free apps can technically be distributed, but without a Security Review, will show an "untrusted app" message on install. Collecting licensing fees outside the Partner Program is prohibited, and doing so can result in your app being disabled and a breach of contract lawsuit being filed. So you don't need a listing to distribute, but you do need to be a Partner and have a contract in place to collect fees on your app.

Comment: I'm getting the feeling that these are two different things. To have the LMA and app distributed with it, does it necessarily need to pass the security review?

Comment: @RenatoOliveira To get the LMA, you must be a Partner (but doesn't require a Security Review). To be listed on the AppExchange, you must pass a Security Review. To simply distribute an app has no technical limitations, but doing so improperly is a contractual breach.

Comment: Thank you very much for the replies! :)